# Delete duplicate rows teradata

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata

im using this query to get all the duplicate rows :

```
SELECT count(*),col1, col2 from table GROUP BY col1, col2 having count(*)>1
```

i tried this query :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (col1, col2) in (SELECT count(*),col1, col2 from table GROUP BY col1, col2
having count(*)>1 )
```

but it doesnt work because of `count(*)` in the select statement.

How can i delete all the duplicate rows of this query ? 
Thanks

Comment: You can simply remove the Count from the Select list. Of course this will delete *all* duplicate rows, but you may want to keep one row...

Comment: You have to use an intermediate table, assuming you don't want to delete all the duplicate rows.

Comment: it works, thank you guys

Comment: You don't have to use an intermediate table. If you are required to run this query on regular basis, you can introduce row_number() function to prioritize sets of fields and delete all rows with row_number() < 1.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using below query if rowid usage is enabled

```
delete from table
where row_id not in (
select max(rowid)  from table 
group by col1,col2 ) TMP
```

OR

1. You can copy all data to a new SET table(get rid of duplicates)
2. Remove all records from main table
3. Re insert all records from newly created SET table to main table

Comment: Your DELETE will remove all unique rows and keep only the duplicates.